# How to call Julia in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, julia, juliacall

I am trying to call Julia within Python so that i can directly use some of the functions in julia to calculate things in python. However, when i try to call it, VScode told me there is no module named 'juliacall'. i have already type "pip install juliacall" in the terminal in VScode, and it looks fine. With "pip list", i did see juliacall is on the list, can anyone tell me what should i do?
Also, in the same directory i have successfully set up the julia environment, just need to get python ready to call it in order to use some functions.

Need someone to help me step by step on how to make my python able to call julia in VScode.
I have looked through the internet and i didn't understand about how to set about the path

Comment: what OS are you on? Also my best guess is that vs code is using a different python/pip version than the one that you are using in your terminal

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am on MacOS, and have realized that it was the Python interpreters that cause the issue, it it now fixed. Still, thanks a lot for your reply! It means so much to a beginner

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually caused by multiple Python interpreters in your environment and not selecting the correct Python interpreter which you installed the python package in.

You can use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the interpreter.

By the way, I suggest you [creating virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment-in-the-terminal) to manage python package.

Comment: Now that I can use juliacall within Python, I want to use a julia package called SGtSNEpi (call julia and use this package within Python). However it does not work out, could you help? Note that I did install the SGtSNEpi package in my julia, therefore i dont understand why it still ask me to add SGtSNEpi

Comment: Here's my code:
from juliacall import Main as jl
import juliacall
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
jl = juliacall.newmodule("SGtSNEpi")
jl.seval("using SparseArrays")
jl.seval("using SGtSNEpi")
G = nx.gnp_random_graph(100, 0.3) # say it's a radom graph we get in python
A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G) # convert it into matrix
Y = jl.sgtsnepi(A) # then put it in the function in julia
Y_py = np.array(Y) # convert the result back
print(Y_py)

Comment: and here's what the terminal returned:
aceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aaronzhong/Desktop/Summer23/demo.py", line 7, in <module>
    jl.seval("using SGtSNEpi")
  File "/Users/aaronzhong/.julia/packages/PythonCall/1f5yE/src/jlwrap/module.jl", line 25, in seval
    return self._jl_callmethod($(pyjl_methodnum(pyjlmodule_seval)), expr)
juliacall.JuliaError: ArgumentError: Package SGtSNEpi not found in current path, maybe you meant `import/using .SGtSNEpi`.
- Otherwise, run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("SGtSNEpi")` to install the SGtSNEpi package.

Comment: @AaronstrugglingCS Hi, glad to know it works. In Stack overflow, it's better to avoid discussions in comments, you can accept my answer and open a new issue to explain your new issue.